# Printing items out of a generator

Tags: python, generator

I am practicing printing out items yielded by a generator function.

This works perfectly fine:

```
def fibonacci():
    a, b = 0, 1
    while True:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b


sumfib = 0
for i in fibonacci():
    if i >= 4000000:
        break
    elif i % 2 == 0:
        sumfib += i

print(sumfib)
```

But the following code is yielding:

```
list1 = ['f', 'o', 'o', 'b', 'a', 'r']
list2 = ['hello', 'world']
list3 = ['1', '2', '3', '4']


def ziplike(*args):
    x = zip(*args)
    yield x


for item in ziplike(list1, list2, list3):
    print(item)
```

What I want to print is each item from each list sequentially, exhausted
when the shortest list is exhausted.  I have it working *without* a generator, but I am trying to wrap my hands around generators.

I want to print this:

```
f
hello
1
o
world
2
```

The first element in each, followed by the second, etc., until the shortest list is exhausted.  I want to be able to feed in any number of iterables, hence my use of `*args`.

*NOTE*  My working, non-generator variant uses itertools:

```
newlist = list(zip(list1, list2, list3))

temp = list(itertools.chain(*newlist))
```

I was trying to avoid that, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your non-generator version work lazily too, just avoid the `list()` calls and use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
newlist = zip(list1, list2, list3)
temp = itertools.chain.from_iterable(newlist)
```

As for your implementation; you yielded the whole `zip()` result, not individual elements from that. Delegate to the `zip()` iterator with `yield from`:

```
def ziplike(*args):
    x = zip(*args)
    yield from x
```

This still produces the row tuples from the `zip()` call; you'd need to loop over each contained tuple too:

```
def ziplike(*args):
    x = zip(*args)
    for tup in x:
        yield from tup
```

to chain the tuple contents.

Demo of the latter:

```
>>> list1 = ['f', 'o', 'o', 'b', 'a', 'r']
>>> list2 = ['hello', 'world']
>>> list3 = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
>>> def ziplike(*args):
...     x = zip(*args)
...     for tup in x:
...         yield from tup
...
>>> for item in ziplike(list1, list2, list3):
...     print(item)
...
f
hello
1
o
world
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Yielding `x` yields the entire iterable. You need to yield *from* `x`.

```
yield from x
```